# Inheriting non-default

Tags: c++, inheritance

Is there a syntax that will allow me to inherit from a class without dflt ctor? For example:

```
template<class T>
struct X : private Y(T)//HERE I'm trying to inherit via cnv (conversion) ctor
{
};
```

Comment: Why all the -'s? That's a well-stated and clear question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely. You just have to call a base constructor explicitly in the derived class's constructor's initializer list

```
struct X {
    X(int a) {}
};

struct Y : X {
    Y() : X(123) {}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
temlate<class T>
struct X : private Y //HERE I'm trying to inherit via cnv (conversion) ctor
{
    X() : Y(...) {}
};
```